# C++ exception handling and error reporting idioms

Tags: c++, exception

In C++, RAII is often advocated as a superior approach to exception handling: if an exception is thrown, the stack is unwound, all the destructors are called and resources are cleaned up.

However, this presents a problem with error *reporting*. Say a very generic function fails, the stack is unwound to the top level and all I see in the logs would be:

> *Couldn't read from socket: connection reset by peer.*

...or any equally generic message. This doesn't say much about the context from which the exception is thrown. Especially if I'm running something like an event queue processing loop.

Of course I could wrap every call to socket reads with a try/catch block, catch the exception, construct a new one with more detailed context information and re-throw it, but it defeats the purpose of having RAII, and is slowly but surely becoming worse than handling return error codes.

What's a better way for detailed for error reporting in standard C++? I'm also open to suggestions involving Boost.

Comment: This sounds like less of a problem with RAII and more of a problem with the fact that C++ exception objects don't provide any inherent context; in other words, you can't get a stack-trace at the catch point that shows where the exception was originally thrown.

Comment: Well, since you're open to Boost, use [Boost.Exception](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html).

Comment: @GMan yes I'm aware of this library, but it doesn't help adding intermediate context (I can already tell a throw site and a catch site with standard C++).

Comment: @Alex B: it helps in the sense that if you go with the catch-and-throw option, then it makes your catch clauses easier to write. You can stuff more context information into the existing exception, instead of constructing a new one.

Comment: Your question conflates the issues of error reporting and resource management in error handling. RAII is solely about resource management. Using exceptions rather than return codes is a matter of ensuring that errors will propagate consistently, and that functions can more often return their semantic 'result'. If you use RAII to its fullest, resources will be released even in code that handles errors via return codes. It's just easier to achieve that via exceptions, because you can't accidentally forget about a function like you can with return codes.

Comment: @Alex: What do you mean?

Comment: @Novelocrat yeah, probably I should say "often used together with RAII", since it advocates not using try/catch blocks.

Comment: @Alex: RAII advocates not using try/catch blocks *for resource management*. It has no "opinion" whether you should use them for other things. I agree that code where every call is wrapped in try/catch is horrible, but that's because it's inherently horrible, it's not horrible because of anything to do with RAII ;-)

Answer (score 5):

As James McNellis suggested here, there is a really neat trick involving a guard object and the `std::uncaught_exception` facility.

The idea is to write code like this:

```
void function(int a, int b)
{
  STACK_TRACE("function") << "a: " << a << ", b: " << b;

  // do anything

}
```

And have the message logged only in case an exception is actually thrown.

The class is very simple:

```
class StackTrace: boost::noncopyable // doesn't make sense to copy it
{
public:
  StackTrace(): mStream() {}

  ~StackTrace()
  {
    if (std::uncaught_exception())
    {
      std::cout << mStream.str() << '\n';
    }
  }

  std::ostream& set(char const* function, char const* file, unsigned int line)
  {
    return mStream << file << "#" << line << " - " << function << " - ";
  }

private:
  std::ostringstream mStream;
};

#define STACK_TRACE(func)                           \
  StackTrace ReallyUnwieldyName;                    \
  ReallyUnwieldyName.set(func, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

One can use `__PRETTY_FUNC__` or equivalent to avoid naming the function, but I have found in practice that it was too mangled / verbose for my own taste.

Note that you need a named object if you wish it to live till the end of the scope, which is the purpose here. We could think of tricky ways to generate a unique identifier, but I have never needed it, even when protecting narrower scope within a function, the rules of name hiding play in our favor.

If you combine this with an `ExceptionManager` (something where exceptions thrown register themselves), then you can get a reference to the latest exception and in case of logging you can rather decide to setup your stack within the exception itself. So that it's printed by `what` and ignored if the exception is discarded.

This is a matter of taste.

Note that in the presence of `ExceptionManager` you must remain aware that not all exceptions can be retrieved with it --> only the ones you have crafted yourself. As such you still need a measure of protection against `std::out_of_range` and 3rd party exceptions.

Comment: Nice "trick". However, since `StackTrace` s ctor will always run, even if there's no error, one should assure that it is as cheap as possible, and that rules out (for me) inserting into a stringstream at construction time! Maybe using a capturing C++0x lambda ` [&]() ` could do the trick ...

Comment: On second thought, the problem seems to be that `uncaught_exception` does not tell you which exception is uncaught and therefore it might be a pretty bad idea to use this in case `std::bad_alloc` is active, which you cannot detect.

Comment: @Martin: this is more a proof of concept than anything else. As you noticed, in case of `bad_alloc` you don't want to request any memory, and therefore you should have the memory preallocated (as much as possible). Also, stack-allocated memory would make this cheaper, which more or less rules out `std::ostringstream`. Using `operator(char const* name, T const& value)` + ad'hoc formatting would allow better performance, using shims would also allow NOT to convert the items to strings if it is not needed, and of course there is the exact strategy that you actually want to execute...

Comment: As in the comments to my answer, note that `uncaught_exception` *does not* tell you whether an exception was thrown from within the scope of your `StackTrace` object. It tells you whether there is an exception active, which is a necessary but not a sufficient condition to imply that a message should be printed. This code can produce spurious error messages. I've never used ExceptionManager, so if it solves this problem I'm keen to see how.

Comment: @Steve: the idea of the ExceptionManager is that user exceptions will be "registered" in the active exception slot when thrown (typically because they share a common base class). Then, instead of logging, you add the various traces to the exception itself, which will only be printed through the `what`. Therefore if the exception is ignored, nothing is printed. What I don't like about it is that if the exception is ignored nothing is printed... of course :) I much prefer systemic tracking of stack unwinding, too many lazy `catch(...)` around for my taste.

Answer (score 4):

I've never actually done this, but you could roll your own "stacktrace":

```
struct ErrorMessage {
    const char *s;
    ErrorMessage(const char *s) : msg(s) {}
    ~ErrorMessage() { if (s) std::cout << s << "\n"; }
    void done() { s = 0; }
};

void someOperation() {
    ErrorMessage msg("Doing the first bit");
    // do various stuff that could throw
    msg = "Doing the second bit";
    // do more stuff that could throw
    msg.done();
}
```

You can have several levels of this (although not necessarily use it at every level):

```
void handleFoo() {
    ErrorMessage msg("Handling foo event");
    someOperation();
    msg.done();
}
```

And add more constructors and members:

```
void handleBar(const BarEvent &b) {
    ErrorMessage msg(std::stringstream("Handling bar event ") << b.id);
    someOperation();
    msg.done();
}
```

And you needn't write the messages to `std::cout`. It could be to some logging object, and the object could queue them, and not actually output them to the log unless the catch site tells it to. That way, if you catch an exception that doesn't warrant logging, nothing is written.

It's not pretty, but it's prettier than try/catch/throw or checking return values. And if you forget to call `done` on success (for example if your function has multiple returns and you miss one), then you will at least see your mistake in the logs, unlike a resource leak.

[Edit: oh, and with a suitable macro you can store `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` in the `ErrorMessage`.]

Comment: One potential alternative to explicitly calling `done()` is to have the destructor call `uncaught_exception()` and only print (or log or whatever) the message if there is an active exception.  While I know the experts say "it's almost never a good idea to use `uncaught_exception()`," I think this particular case might be okay because it's one of the few times that you really do want different behavior depending on whether the destructor was called as a result of normal end-of-scope or due to stack unwinding.  At least, I did that in a hobby project and didn't run into any trouble with it.

Comment: @Steve:  I too am usually pretty stunned when I might be right.  :-P

Comment: @James: After reviewing the relevant GOTW, the case where checking `uncaught_exception` in the destructor goes wrong, is when some other destructor calls code with an ErrorMessage in it (for example a `flush` function might reasonably want to log on error), suitably surrounded by try/catch, and then that destructor is called during stack unwinding. The error message in the `flush` function will be printed even if the `flush` didn't throw an exception. I *think* this can be fixed by checking `uncaught_exception` in the constructor too, but I'm not sure.

Comment: That's "fixed" in the sense that we suppress the error message regarding `flush`, on the basis that we already have an exception to worry about. It's still not perfect, since it might be useful for the log to show that the flush failed as well as the first thing failing. But we know that if `uncaught_exception` is true when we create our ErrorMessage, then any exceptions thrown will be suppressed. So suppress the message too, why not? Amusingly, Sutter might have had an ulterior motive in declaring `uncaught_exception` immoral: http://world.std.com/~swmcd/steven/ms/bugs.html

Comment: Ha ha; that GOTW was written before he joined the VC++ team at Microsoft :-) (and, VC++ actually supports it correctly now anyway).  When I used it, it was for a much more limited purpose and no constructor or destructor was going to do anything that would create an `ErrorMessage`.  I don't really like the "just suppress messages from exceptions thrown in a dtor" idea... you might actually want the information where you handle the exception since you can handle it before the dtor returns.  Another option would be to use an ExceptionHandler object to keep track of active exceptions.

Comment: (I admit, when I used `uncaught_exception()` for this, I wasn't using it for general exception handling; it was only being used for reporting diagnostic messages from a compiler; making it work in the general case may be a lot more work; I'll have to dig it up and play with it)

Comment: @SteveJessop I eventually came to the same idea of checking `uncaught_exception` in both the constructor and destructor for a very similar need to log on execption:  [Question 15504166](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504166/how-should-one-log-when-an-exception-is-triggered)

Answer (score 4):

> Say a very generic function fails, the stack is unwound to the top level and all I see in the logs would be [...]
>   What's a better way for detailed for error reporting in standard C++?

Error handling isn't local to a class or library - it is a application level concern.

Best I can answer you question is that the error reporting should be always implemented by looking first and foremost at the error handling. (And the *error handling* also including the handling of the error by the user.) Error handling is the decision making about what has to be done about the error.

That is one of the reasons why error reporting is an application level concern and strongly depends on the application workflow. In one application the "connection reset by peer" is a fatal error - in another it is a norm of life, error should be silently handled, connection should be reestablished and pending operation retried.

Thus the approach you mention - *catch the exception, construct a new one with more detailed context information and re-throw it* - is a valid one too: it is up to the top level application logic (or even user configuration) to decide whether the error is really an error or some special (re)action has to taken upon the condition.

What you have encountered is one of the weaknesses of so called out-of-line error handling (aka exceptions). And I'm not aware of any way to do it better. Exceptions create a secondary code path in the application and if error reporting is vital the design of the secondary code path has to treated just like the main code path.

Obvious alternative to the out-of-line error handling is the in-line error handling - good ol' return codes and log messages on the error conditions. That allows for a trick where application saves all low-severity log messages into internal (circular) buffer (of fixed or configurable size) and dumps them into the log only if high-severity error happens. This way more context information is available and different layers of application do not have to be actively aware of each other. That is also standard (and sometimes literally "standard" - mandated by law) way of error reporting in application fields like safety and mission critical software, were one is not allowed to miss errors.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a call stack to your exception. I'm not sure how good this works for release builds but works like a charm with debug. You could do this in the constructor of your exception (to encapsulate it). See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/StackWalker.aspx) for a starting point. This is possible as well on Linux - eventhough I dont remember how exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I use RAII and exceptions and just have various unit-test-like assert statements throughout the code - if they fail, the the stack unwinds to where I can catch and handle them.

```
#define APP_ASSERT_MSG(Class,Assertion,szDescription)   \
    if ( !(Assertion) )                                \
    {                                                  \
        throw Class(__LINE__,__FILE__,szDescription);  \
    }
```

For most of my particular use case, all I care about is logging debug information, so my exception has the file and line number in it along with an error message (message is optional as I have an assert without it as well).  You could easily add **FUNCTION** or an error code of some type for better handling.

I can then use it like this:

```
int nRet = download_file(...);
APP_ASSERT_MSG(DownloadException == ERR_OK, "Download failed");
```

This makes error handling and reporting much easier.

For really nasty debugging, I used GCC's function instrumentation to keep a trace list of what's going on.  It works well, but slows down the app quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

What I do regularly, FWIW, is not use exceptions, but rather explicit error handling in a standard format (ie: using a macro). For example:

```
result = DoSomething();
CHECK_RESULT_AND_RETURN_ON_ERROR( result );
```

Now, obviously, this has many limitations design-wise:

- Your return codes may need to be somewhat uniform

  Code is cluttered with macros

  You may need many macros for various check conditions

The upside, though, is as Dummy00001 said: you can effectively generate a stack trace on demand in the event of a serious error, by simply caching the results. I also use this paradigm to log all unexpected error conditions, so I can adjust the code later to handle unexpected conditions which occur "in the wild".

That's my 2c.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Boost and STL, which do throw exceptions. So exception-less code doesn't play well with it.

Comment: Yeah, no great solutions there... you usually end up wrapping STL/boost calls with try/catch blocks anyway. Still prefer my solution in general for my code/functions, and just have higher-level handlers for unexpected library exceptions, but mixing the paradigms can get messy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I handle error reporting in my libraries (this may or may not suit your situation).

First, as part of your design you want a "core" or "system" library that all this common logic will sit in. All you other libraries will then link to the core and use its error reporting APIs, so your whole system has a single compact chunk of logic for handling this mess.

Inside the core, provide a set of logging MACROS such as "LogWarning" and "LogFatal" with documented behavior and expected usage- for example, LogFatal should trigger a hard abort of the process but anything lower than "LogError" is simply advisory (does nothing). The macros can provide a "printf" interface that automatically appends the "LINE", "FILE", and "FUNC" macros as arguments to the underlying singleton object that handles your error reporting.

For the object itself I'll defer to you. However, you want public APIs that configure your "drains"- e.g. log to stderr, log to logfile, log to MS Services log, etc. You also want the underlying singleton to be thread safe, re-entrant where possible, and very robust.

With this system, you can make "exception reporting" ONE MORE DRAIN TYPE. Just add an internal API to that error manager object that packages your logged message as an exception, then throws it. Users can then enable AND DISABLE exceptions-on-error behavior in your code with ONE LINE in their apps. You can put try-catches around 3rd party or system code in you libraries that then calls a "Log..." macro in the catch clauses to enable clean re-throw behavior (with certain platforms and compiler options you can even catch things like segfaults using this).